# How to style the spinner from a number input in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, input

Since a couple of versions (since 29 I think) Firefox adds spinner buttons to a number input. But they do not fit into my Bootstrap powered website. Is there a way to style these buttons so they look less ugly.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can style them, but maybe hiding them will already help:

```
/* Hide spinners for Firefox */
input[type=number] {
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
}

/* Hide spinners for Chrome */
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: what's the purpose of `margin: 0` in the webkit spinners?